# Why can I not declare a variable whose structure has been defined?

Tags: c, windows, compiler-errors, macros, c-preprocessor

**This problem might not be so easy to solve as you first think.**

FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER is a structure defined in the header file fltUserStructures.h that is a standard Windows SDK header file located at the SDK include path, i.e.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Include\shared\fltUserStructures.h".

```
typedef struct _FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER {

    //
    //  OUT
    //
    //  Total buffer length in bytes, including the FILTER_REPLY_HEADER, of
    //  the expected reply.  If no reply is expected, 0 is returned.
    //

    ULONG ReplyLength;

    //
    //  OUT
    //
    //  Unique Id for this message.  This will be set when the kernel message
    //  satifies this FilterGetMessage or FilterInstanceGetMessage request.
    //  If replying to this message, this is the MessageId that should be used.
    //

    ULONGLONG MessageId;

    //
    //  General filter-specific buffer data follows...
    //

} FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER, *PFILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER;
```

However, the following code cannot be compiled by the VC++ 2012.

```
#include <fltUserStructures.h>

int main()
{
    //
    // error C2065: 'FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER' : undeclared identifier
    //
    FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER v; 
}
```

or

```
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000000 // Vista or later
#include <FltUser.h>

int main()
{
    //
    // fltuserstructures.h(27): fatal error C1012:
    // unmatched parenthesis : missing ')'
    //
    FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER v; 
}
```

Although I had tried many methods, the compiler always rejected the code above. What is the root cause?

Comment: For those of us who don't have Windows SDKs installed, what does the definition of the structure look like?

Comment: Try including FltUser.h instead

Comment: @André, including FltUser.h instead will generate another error: fatal error C1012: unmatched parenthesis : missing ')'

Comment: not sure why this got downvoted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That structure (and much of what's in `fltUserStructures.h` is conditionally compiled based on `FLT_MGR_BASELINE` which in turn is set in `fltUser.h`:

```
#define FLT_MGR_BASELINE (((OSVER(NTDDI_VERSION) == NTDDI_WIN2K) && (SPVER(NTDDI_VERSION) >= SPVER(NTDDI_WIN2KSP4))) || \
                          ((OSVER(NTDDI_VERSION) == NTDDI_WINXP) && (SPVER(NTDDI_VERSION) >= SPVER(NTDDI_WINXPSP2))) || \
                          ((OSVER(NTDDI_VERSION) == NTDDI_WS03)  && (SPVER(NTDDI_VERSION) >= SPVER(NTDDI_WS03SP1))) ||  \
                          (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA))
```

So, `#include <fltuser.h>` instead, and make sure that `NTDDI_VERSION` is set appropriately (using `WINVER`,for example):

```
#define WINVER 0x0600
#include <windows.h>
#include <fltUser.h>

int main()
{
    //
    // error C2065: 'FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER' : undeclared identifier
    //
    FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER v; 
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. "fatal error C1012: unmatched parenthesis : missing ')'"

Comment: The revised version doesn't work yet. "sdkddkver.h(264): fatal error C1189: #error :  NTDDI_VERSION setting conflicts with _WIN32_WINNT setting"

Comment: I copied the code from your post. i.e. #define WINVER 0x0600
#include <windows.h>
#include <fltUser.h>

Comment: Looks like your project is already setting `_WIN32_WINNT` - change it to indicate you want Vista APIs (`0x0600`). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx for the awful details.

Comment: it really works this time. The root cause is just as you has pointed out.